# Upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 in chroot'ed environment?

Tags: upgrade, android, chroot

Currently I use a Ubuntu 20.04 running on my Android phone. It is a chroot'ed environment running as a subsystem under Android. It is called 'Andronix' which cooperates with 'Termux' a package based terminal app under Android. Andronix allows running several ARM64 distros which can be accessed by VNC from any VNC app from any device which has network access to the Android device. For me it works fine, there is a full fledged desktop Firefox 101, Libreoffice, Stellarium which work much better than the stripped down Android versions of these apps.
Now I want to upgrade to 22.04, but, as it is proot'ed, a full upgrade is not possible as it requires DBUS and kernel access which can only done by Android itself. Even despite my device is rooted (for other purposes) the Termux / Andronix combination does not make use of it, except that I have disabled SELinux, which is enabled by default.

The command `sudo apt dist-upgrade` won't work from a terminal within Andronix, while the regular `sudo apt upgrade` does work when updates are available.
But is there an alternative way to `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to upgrade the OS except the kernel / DBUS just within the Andronix environment ?